# Регулярное выражение php, с чего начинается число

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Сейчас нахожу в строке с помощью рег выражение число размером 14 символов:

```
preg_match('([0-9]{14})', $record[8], $matches)
```

Все работает, но понадобилось проверка что первые 3 символа являются числом **157** как это можно сделать?

Comment: `(157[0-9]{11})`

Comment: Помог ли вам мой ответ? Кстати, уточните, пожалуйста, текст целиком состоит из числа или это длинный текст, в котором есть нужное вам число?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
preg_match('~(?<!\d)157\d{11}(?!\d)~', $record[8], $match)
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ng0ZKo/1)

Блоки просмотра назад и вперёд - `(?<!\d)` / `(?!\d)` - помогут найти только такие последовательности 14 цифр, перед которыми и после которых нет других цифр.

Чтобы задать начальное значение `157`, эти цифры подставляются в выражение, а следующие 11 цифр легко найти с помощью `\d{11}`.